# A place where the sun is up

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> A place where the sun is up,
>   The land that is cut from all. 
>   Here the people coverup, 
>   Once had men come by crawl.

Might be too broad, will post more lines later!

Comment: Its 5 'oclock somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> Japan

A place where the sun is up,

> Known as the land of the rising sun

The land that is cut from all.

> It's an island nation

Here the people coverup,

> The traditional kimono covers most of the body

Once had men come by crawl.

> Trench warfare in world war II?

Comment: You're right! but last two clues are off.

Comment: Could the cover up clue potentially be either rot13(avawn be trvfun) and the last clue relate to rot13(freinagf univat gb penjy nsgre znfgref)

Answer (score 3):

Is it maybe:

> the poles?

A place where the sun is up,

> In summertime, the sun is always above the horizon at the North Pole, and the opposite stands for South Pole, because the Earth is tilted.

The land that is cut from all.

> Poles are cut from other land.

Here the people coverup,

> It's freakishly cold, they better do!

Once had men come by crawl.

> Not really sure, but for humans (maybe better say explorers) is very hard there. Especially when you go to sleep you need to crawl in you tent/sleeping bag/any kind of hideout.. maybe that explains the last part?

Answer (score 2):

This attempt is an addendum to the answer from @jafe:

> Japan

Here the people coverup,

> Ninjas are essentially **covert** operatives

Once had men come by crawl.

> Yobai, or "night **crawling**", involved **men** "silently enter[ing] houses with [...] women" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yobai))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe-

> Deserts

Explanation-

> Always sunny and hot, people cover up because of the sun and sand, and thirst can often make you crawl.

Comment: ooooh not quite!

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess:

> Antarctica

A place where the sun is up,

> Well... right now it's springtime there and the sun is starting to come up. It'll be there for quite a while.

The land that is cut from all.

> Literally.

Here the people coverup,

> Walking around without a thick layer of clothing would be unpleasant.

Once had men come by crawl.

> Antarctic explorers of old? Probably crawling was involved at times.